# Firefox keeps the classes which got added in an animation on scroll

Tags: javascript

I wanted to have some animation on some elements based on their place on the window innerHeight. I wrote this code, which works just fine on Chrome but on Firefox it works fine for 1st time after any change on my code and then keeps the classes which got added through JavaScript *after refreshing*:

```
const Elements = document.querySelectorAll("h1,p");
let AnimateOnScroll = (scrolledTop) => {
    Elements.forEach(Element => {

        if (scrolledTop + window.innerHeight > Element.offsetTop + Element.offsetHeight) {
            Element.classList.add("active");
        } else {
        }
    });
};
AnimateOnScroll(0);
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    const scrolledTop = window.scrollY;
    AnimateOnScroll(scrolledTop);
});
```

Is something wrong with my code? Why Firefox keeps the added classes even after refreshing?

Comment: Add a `console.log("Called");` statement in your `AnimateOnScroll` function, scroll the page and refresh. Is that statement logged? I'm noticing that if you scroll and refresh your page, you'll be at the same spot on the page as before you refreshed. I think this is just being called again, and not "keeping the classes from before refresh".

Comment: Some browsers keep the scroll position after refreshing. It may be possible that firefox fires the event when the page loads.

Comment: when I remove this line AnimateOnScroll(0); it works fine :-? on FireFox but what should I do with the first element then when the page is not scrolled :-? When I replace scroll with DOMContentLoaded nothing gets animated :|

Comment: @AbramPlus Please refrain from using [too many smileys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172143/do-we-have-a-policy-on-smileys). It makes your question / comments harder to read.

Comment: You're not getting attacked, and you don't need to shut up. It's just really hard to read what you're saying when it's littered with `:-?`, `:|`, etc. Just write your question/comments with a little more professionalism in mind; it goes a long way in encouraging people to A) treat your question seriously and B) actually provide help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe preserving the classes may be one of their feature based on this [preserving states](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=654072).

I would do a document ready and check if the class is there and remove it if it is.

Keep the other code as is and just add this

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => { 
    Elements.forEach(Element => { 
    Element.classList.remove("active"); 
  }); 
})
```

Not optimized and not sure how to. If anyone can correct me that would be great.

Comment: Dude I listened to your advice and changed my code to this >>const Elements= document.querySelectorAll("h1,p");
const scrolledTop = window.scrollY;

window.addEventListener("load",()=>{

Elements.forEach(Element=>{

    if(scrolledTop + window.innerHeight / 2 > Element.offsetTop){

Element.classList.add("active");}
});

});    But now the first Element gets animated but no others which are on other sections.

Comment: Sorry, maybe it wasn't clear enough. I meant add an on load event to removed 'active' class from any element that has it. So the other stuff remain the same, you just have to add this:


window.addEventListener("load", () => { 
 Elements.forEach(Element => { 
   Element.classList.remove("active"); 
  }); 
})